# how to update a wxlistbox from a different class?

Tags: python, wxpython

i have a wxlistbox in a class and i want to update the data inside the listbox from a different class.Is i possible to reload the class while leave the control from another class?if yes ,how?

eg:
i have two classes,Class A and Class B.In class A there is a wxlistbox.while starting the program class A initilise the wxlistbox and bind some values.when a button inside class A clicked it call another frame class B.while close the frame B the wxlistbox inside class A should update.
My question is how to refresh listbox while close the frame B?

Comment: your question is not clear. Tell us what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the SetItems() method, which according to the docs does the following: "Clear and set the strings in the control from a list".

Edit: myListCtrl.SetItems(ListOfStrings)

That will replace all the items in the control with whatever is in the list.

Comment: cant get what u mean?i want to reload the wxListBox.please give me an example __Thanks__

Comment: I added a tiny little explanatory note. See also http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ItemContainer-class.html

Comment: So you either pass a reference from one class to another or you use pubsub: http://bit.ly/an9yBw

Comment: Or you could use PostEvent too, although I like pubsub better